# % of revenue chnage from previous month and previous year of same month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input Data

```
    Date         State  Revenue 
   31-01-2020     M       100
   05-05-2020     M       500
   05-05-2020     k       500
   31-05-2020     M       100
   12-04-2021     K       250
   15-04-2021     M       300
   20-05-2021     K       250
   21-05-2021     M       300
```

Expected Output:

Only for the Month of May'21

```
Month  STATE Total_Revenue  % change of revenue compared to the previous month of the state     % change of revenue compared to same month from previous year for the state
May'21  M
        K
```

Comment: stackoverflow is designed to help you with problems and errors, not do the work for an assignment. For this you would sum up the revenues for each month, calculate the rolling average and then put it back together in the desired format. Try ChatGPT, it will likely do the job for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using periods and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['period'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')

tmp = df.groupby(['period', 'State'], as_index=False)['Revenue'].sum()

def percentage_change(col1, col2):
    return ((col2 - col1) / col1) * 100

out = (
 tmp.merge(tmp.assign(period=lambda d: d['period'].add(1)),
           on=['period', 'State'], suffixes=(None, '_prev_month'), how='left')
    .merge(tmp.assign(period=lambda d: d['period'].add(12)),
           on=['period', 'State'], suffixes=(None, '_prev_year'), how='left')
 
    .assign(**{'%change_month': lambda d: percentage_change(d['Revenue'], d['Revenue_prev_month']),
               '%change_year': lambda d: percentage_change(d['Revenue'], d['Revenue_prev_year']),
              })
)
```

Output:

```
    period State  Revenue  Revenue_prev_month  Revenue_prev_year  %change_month  %change_year
0  2020-01     M      100                 NaN                NaN            NaN           NaN
1  2020-05     K      500                 NaN                NaN            NaN           NaN
2  2020-05     M      600                 NaN                NaN            NaN           NaN
3  2021-04     M      300                 NaN                NaN            NaN           NaN
4  2021-05     K      250                 NaN              500.0            NaN         100.0
5  2021-05     M      300               300.0              600.0            0.0         100.0
6  2021-12     K      250                 NaN                NaN            NaN           NaN
```